# When is it suitable to use PrimeFaces DialogFramework over declarative <p:dialog/>?

Tags: primefaces

I am looking for concrete use cases (except for displaying `FacesMessage`s) where it is suitable or even better to use the PrimeFaces DialogFramework instead of the declarative `<p:dialog/>` in general and in terms of general coding standards (such as [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)), maintainability, responsiveness etc.?

So far, `<p:dialog/>` served my needs and I cannot think of a concrete example where I would prefer to use the DialogFramework API over the declarative approach. Personally, I find it way more simpler (shorter code, you can directly see in xhtml that a dialog is opened by `PF('someDialog').show();`) and a lot more maintainable (no mix-up of xhtml or even html and Java code, keeping responsibilities clean) to use the declarative approach. Feel free to correct me if my findings turn out to be nonsense.

Comment: One major difference is that the pages that you load in the dialogFramework are fully self contained regarding scoping. So it is a fully new view that is created via a get request. So it can have its own viewscoped beans etc...  Effectively the same as loading it in a new browser tab

Comment: OK, I see. So far, my dialog-related fields are located in the controller class that handles the main page actions. The "main page" meaning the page that is calling the dialog. Your approach looks great for re-using code.